# http put request causes "net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, http, request

I have an Angular client issuing http put request to rails backend.

http request code is like following:

```
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/documents/' + $scope.document_id,
        data: parameter
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("Error has occurred while getting user document data from the server");
        });
```

Data I'm passing is like following and it is a valid JSON:

```
        var parameter = {
  "document": {
    "title": "I-129",
    "data": JSON.stringify($scope.formData),
    "user_id": 1
  }
}
```

Backend code is like folloiwng:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.update(document_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @document, notice: 'Document was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @document }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Server log I'm getting:

```
Started PUT "/documents/3" for ::1 at 2016-04-20 00:24:12 -0700
Processing by DocumentsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"document"=>{"title"=>"I-129", "data"=>"{\"text_id\":\"1111\",\"Date_id\":\"1111-11-11T08:00:00.000Z\",\"number_id\":11111222}", "user_id"=>0}, "id"=>"3"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  Document Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Document Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "documents" WHERE ("documents"."title" = 'I-129' AND "documents"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/documents/3
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Whenever I issue put request, I get an error saying

> http://localhost:3000/documents/3 net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

What am I doing wrong here? And I confirm that I can do the http put request through Paw (similar program to Postman) on URL(`'http://localhost:3000/documents/' + $scope.document_id`).

Comment: Please show us the backend code as well.

Comment: Added it in the body.

Comment: in the backend log you can see if the rails app is rendering the html or json. Can you verify or post the logs?

Comment: it renders bunch of both types of files. At the end, it renders index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log you can see that rails is treating the call as HTML

```
Processing by DocumentsController#update as HTML
```

Try adding this to the http call

```
 dataType: "json",
 headers: {
     "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     "Accept" : "application/json"
 }
```

Comment: Still no luck. Giving me a same error. One thinig I notice that my user_id in document is set as 0 after the error. And the log stays same.

Comment: Backend in rails so we can try something...  try to add .json to your url

Comment: Add also the Accept in the headers (see the modified answere)

Comment: if I add '.json' at the end, it does change the data without an error. But it is kept deleting `user_id` in document. Any thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109636/discussion-between-rick-and-kahsn).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
url: 'http://localhost:3000/documents/' + $scope.document_id + '.json'
```

and

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @document.update(document_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @document, notice: 'Document was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render json: @document, status: :ok}
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
dataType: "json",
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```